# MySQL View with Conditional Sum

Tags: mysql

I’m trying to create a view that SUMS a table column based on two other columns (id and class), but I’m struggling with the inner query, or at least I think thats the problem.

The VIEW is not recognizing the ‘id’ column and thus is summing the entire column for each id.

I’ve left my attempts out of the fiddle for simplicity and easier understanding.

Here is my sample data...

```
CREATE TABLE Table1 (id INT,class varchar(10),amount varchar(50));

INSERT INTO Table1 (id,class,amount) 
VALUES
(1,'A',.25),
(1,'B',.25),
(1,'B',.25),
(1,'C',.25),
(1,'C',.25),
(1,'C',.25),
(2,'A',.25),
(2,'B',.25),
(2,'B',.25),
(2,'C',.25),
(2,'C',.25),
(2,'C',.25);
```

...and fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e6aa3d66e791936779ea3a4c5b0d8580

```
CREATE TABLE Table1 (id INT,class varchar(10),amount varchar(50));

CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW View1 AS

select id,
    concat_ws(' / ',
        concat_ws('','A:',(select  coalesce(SUM(amount),0)
                            from Table1
                            where class = 'A')),
        concat_ws('','B:',(select  coalesce(SUM(amount),0)
                            from Table1
                        where class = 'B')),
        concat_ws('','C:',(select  coalesce(SUM(amount),0)
                            from Table1
                            where class = 'C'))

    ) as totals
from Table1
group by id
```

The expected outcome for each id should be:
A: 0.25 / B: 0.50 / C: 0.75

Comment: Take `GROUP BY` out of the main query. The conditionals are doing the grouping.

Comment: @Barmar but they want it grouped by class *and* id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of grouping with conditionals, just do grouped sums in a subquery, then concatenate them.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW View1 AS

SELECT id, GROUP_CONCAT(class, ': ', ROUND(total, 2) ORDER BY class SEPARATOR '/') AS totals
FROM (
    SELECT id, class, SUM(amount) AS total
    FROM Table1
    GROUP BY id, class
) AS x
GROUP BY id
```

[Fiddle](http://CREATE%20OR%20REPLACE%20VIEW%20View1%20AS%20%20SELECT%20id,%20GROUP_CONCAT(class,%20%27:%20%27,%20total%20ORDER%20BY%20class%20SEPARATOR%20%27/%27)%20AS%20totals%20FROM%20(%20%20%20%20%20SELECT%20id,%20class,%20SUM(amount)%20AS%20total%20%20%20%20%20FROM%20Table1%20%20%20%20%20GROUP%20BY%20id,%20class%20)%20AS%20x%20GROUP%20BY%20id)

Comment: Thanks, that works, but it’s not summing correctly. I changed the values and summing .10+.10+.10 is returning .30000004. Why? See fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=9d7d0c17aa4030042609289ee3d927c4

Comment: Use `ROUND(total, 2)` to round to 2 decimal places

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken

Comment: Why are you storing `amount` as a `VARCHAR` instead of `DECIMAL`?

Comment: there are strings in the column. I understand it’s not best practice and will rebuild in the future. Would I round the sum(amount)?

Comment: I've updated the answer to show where to round.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id,class, SUM(amount) FROM Table1 GROUP BY id,class;
```